# Splash blocking JS execution

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, splash-screen

i am try to use scrapy-splash to render some website with js interation, but if i use `splash:wait()` , js execution is blocked and some validations failed:

```
2019-03-12 19:20:08.852022 [network] [139640539265848] GET http://127.0.0.1:17556/
2019-03-12 19:20:08.883925 [network-manager] Download error 403: unknown error (http://127.0.0.1:7054/)
```

but i don't use `splash:wait`.. splash return invalid response without wait JS validations.. and splash logs tell me that request was executed after return splash response:

```
2019-03-12 19:33:12.165731 [events] {"maxrss": 226184, "rendertime": 0.6243276596069336, "active": 0, "timestamp": 1552419192, "qsize": 0, "client_ip": "172.17.0.10", "load": [0.6, 0.52, 0.51], "_id": 139640539265176, "path": "/execute", "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0", "status_code": 200, "method": "POST", "args": {"lua_source": "\n    function main(splash, args)\n        \n        splash.private_mode_enabled = false\n        assert(splash:go{\n            splash.args.url,\n            headers=splash.args.headers,\n            http_method=splash.args.http_method,\n            body=splash.args.body,\n        })\n        \n        local entries = splash:history()\n        local last_response = entries[#entries].response\n        print(\"leoooooooo\")\n        print(last_response)\n        return {\n            \n            html = splash:html(),\n        }\n    end", "proxy": "http://neoway:mp7Bs18ErS@179.61.205.166:60000", "url": "http://consultas.transparencia.mt.gov.br/pessoal/servidores_ativos_orgao/resultado_3.php?mes=1&ano=2017&orgao=7&ficha=125164849", "uid": 139640539265176, "headers": {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Referer": "http://consultas.transparencia.mt.gov.br/pessoal/servidores_ativos_orgao/resultado_3.php?mes=1&ano=2017&orgao=7&ficha=125164849", "Host": "consultas.transparencia.mt.gov.br", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}, "cookies": [], "wait": 10}, "fds": 23}
2019-03-12 19:33:12.166175 [pool] SLOT 0 is available
2019-03-12 19:33:12.178595 [network] [139640539265176] GET http://127.0.0.1:4444/
2019-03-12 19:33:12.182496 [network] [139640539265176] GET http://127.0.0.1:4653/
```

i trying to render this webseite

> http://consultas.transparencia.mt.gov.br/pessoal/servidores_ativos_orgao/resultado_3.php?mes=1&ano=2017&orgao=7&ficha=125164849

lua script:

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(5))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

Have other way to wait JS execution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with the URL and Lua script (+ wait)? Also, `wait()` shouldn't block Javascript, as the whole point is to wait for the site to finish processing.

Comment: sure. question updated.

Comment: I tried your example yesterday and it gave me a CAPTCHA prompt. I tried the same code today and it returned a screenshot of the correct page. I tried it again now, and it's giving me the CAPTCHA. This definitely isn't because of `wait` blocking Javascript, but rather some bot detection mechanism they use.

Comment: I try render this page using puppeteer com parameter slowMo (turn puppeteet more slow) and.. always get correctly page.. without captcha validation.. have similar parameter  `slowMo` in splash? how i could run splash more slow?

Comment: I think you might just've been lucky when you used Puppeteer's `slowMo`. I'm not aware of a Splash instruction to slow down everything. Besides, at the point of failure you've only given it one instruction anyway (open URL), so there isn't a lot you can slow down. Either way. I don't believe it's going to help you. That website uses F5 Networks bot detection. You can read a bit more [here](https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2017/10/10/understanding-f5-bobcmn-javascript-detection/). It seems like you need to get and set the proper cookies, instead of just jumping directly to that page.

Comment: thanks for help! thanks for the link and explanation.. but i think that splash isn't construct cookie correctly because splash blocking local request for some reason that i don't understand..  i update lua script to get cookies and re passing to request again.. and always come captcha validation.. comparing browser cookies and splash cookies.. splash cookies is incomplete, don't have some ids..

Comment: that i notice and seems very odd is that don't using wait.. splash logs tell me that local request are executed with success.. why? other odd behavior is splash some time render page correctly.. and some times not.. why?